# ODAP not working in web appliaction on 64 bit operating system

Tags: oracle, provider

When try to use ODAP(Oracle.DataAccess.dll version 2.112.1.0) under "64 bit" operating system with VS2012
In windows application it works fine but when try to use it under website an exception raised

Exception message : The type initializer for 'Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleCommand' threw an exception
Inner exception  : The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client

Comment: Is the web server running on the same machine as the Windows app?

Answer (score 0):

Did you install the ODP (Oracle Data Provider for .NET) on the machine? It is not part of the standard Oracle Instant Client, you have to enable it in Oracle Installer.

In such case the error message "The provider is not compatible with the version of Oracle client" is quite misleading!